# Add VALUES + INDEX to ActiveX ComboBox in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

How can I add items and an index to a combo box, I've got the below, but it says it's an invalid argument:

```
Me.lstDataSet.AddItem wsB.Range("B5"), wsB.Range("A5")
```

`A5` is an integer (index) value [34] and `B5` is a string/date (actual) value [04 Jan 2012].  For reference, code that comes before this imports the last updated/inserted record from a database.

What I want to achieve is to have the combobox display [ 001 | String Value ], ie display two columns, which I can then reference later.

Answer (score 0):

to add items to the second column, use `.List`

```
Me.ComboBox1.Clear
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "1"
Me.ComboBox1.List(0, 1) = "testing" ' add text in second column (0 based array)
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "2342"
Me.ComboBox1.List(Me.ComboBox1.ListCount-1, 1) = "more testing" 
' add it to last item added, no need to remember where you are
```